# Can facebook access token be used for someone else's data?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-fql

Does facebook allow to use one person's access token to fetch post info of another person (post comments, likes)?

I am thinking of implementing a pool of tokens in my app, so if token is broken I can use other persons token. Wondering if it's allowed and whether facebook have some restrictions on such a use case.

Additionally, I am currently using FQL, is there a difference for Graph API in  how tokens work?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It is not possible. That would be an incredibly large privacy problem anyway.

Also, for user postings you need the "read_stream" permission and you probably will not get this one approved:

> This permission is reserved for apps that replicate the Facebook
>   client on platforms that don’t have a native client.

(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0)

About FQL: There is no difference, although keep in mind that FQL is deprecated and will be removed when support for v2.0 runs out. See this link for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions#versioning

(thanx to Tobi for clarification)

Comment: FQL will not be removed in April, but 2 years after the version after the current v2.0 is announced. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions#versioning `A version will no longer be usable two years after the date that the subsequent version is released.`

Comment: ah, you are right. it will be available until April 2016. i will edit my answer.

Comment: No, it's not even available until April 2016! v2.0 is the last version  which supports FQL, and per what I wrote before, it will be usable *two years after the subsequent version (for v2.0!) is released*

Comment: snap. now that would be 2017 then. i was under the impression that they make a special rule for FQL not to support it anymore next year...

Comment: ha, now i got it. it depends on the next version, of course :)